# Exporting scraped content to google sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am willing to scrape a website for some information. It would be 3 to 4 columns. The difficult part is, i want to export all the data in to the google sheets and make the crawler run after some specific intervals. I 'll be using scrapy for this purpose. Any suggestions on how can i do this (by making custom pipeline or any other way as i don't have much experience in writing custom pipelines)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Google API** and  python **pygsheets** module. 
Refer this link for more details [Click Here](https://erikrood.com/Posts/py_gsheets.html)

Please see the sample code and this might help you.

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
#authorization
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='/Users/desktop/creds.json')

# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column
df['name'] = ['John', 'Steve', 'Sarah']

#open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
sh = gc.open('PY to Gsheet Test')

#select the first sheet 
wks = sh[0]

#update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2. 
wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))
```